# Jquery: Convert string to boolean

Tags: jquery, hidden-field

I'm pooling the following values from some hidden fields.

```
var hfEntityBool = $(this).find('input[id*="hfEntityBool"]').val();
if (hfEntityBool) {
    alert(hfEntityBool);
}
```

No matter what the value of the hidden field, the alert still displays. Any reason for that?

I've tried to use **Boolean(hfEntityBool)** method in case the hidden field's still a string, but nothing changed.

Thank for helping

Comment: What does the alert show?

Comment: @LeeMeador OP means the alert shows irrespective of whether `hfEntityBool` is `true` or `false` :)

Comment: What is the value of `hfEntityBool` when it is being evaluated in the `if` block?  Check out [this for a reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FReference%2FOperators%2FLogical_Operators)

Comment: The 3rd line of code has an `alert()` call. What text appears in the popup box for that alert?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It depends on the value you're expecting in the hidden field.

I would do something like this:

```
var hfEntityBool = $(this).find('input[id*="hfEntityBool"]').val() == "true";
if (hfEntityBool) {
    alert(hfEntityBool);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try :

```
if(hfEntityBool.length){...} // (or hfEntityBool.length > 0)
```

What does the console show for this :

```
console.log('nb char of hfEntityBool : '+hfEntityBool.length);//before if
```